# How to correct XLOOKUP Formula result Error with query

Tags: google-sheets

i created year expenses sheet with query, xlookup formula in google sheet. now getting error with xlookup formula. can u check my google sheet and correct xlookup formula. i share my sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/106FpEvx5NBo_bX_0XyBVBsZhotYqMFzGkMYI_JFpRwE/edit?usp=sharing

pl correct my xlookup formula

my code

=QUERY(DATA!B2:D, "WHERE B CONTAINS '"&XLOOKUP(B2,DATA!H2:H,DATA!I2:I)&"' ",0)

Comment: can someone please resolve the issue. Team (Stack overflow)

Answer (score 1):

added formula to your sheet. Please check it out:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({DATE(RIGHT(DATA!B2:B,4),MID(DATA!B2:B,4,2),LEFT(DATA!B2:B,2)),DATA!C2:D},"SELECT *"&IF(B2="2022 ALL MONTH EXPENSES",," WHERE MONTH(Col1) = "&MONTH(XLOOKUP(B2,DATA!H3:H,DATA!I3:I))-1)))`